# Extract Visio diagram from word document using open xml?

Tags: c#, parsing, openxml, openxml-sdk

I am trying to parse the word document, It has visio diagram and images. I am not able to extract diagram and save it in visio format (.vsd, .vdx, .vsdx, .vsdm) Using C# Open XML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found and answer to my own question. below is the code if any one its..

Below code will help you get all the image in  word document.

```
foreach (ImagePart imagePart in doc.MainDocumentPart.ImageParts)
{
    var uri = imagePart.Uri;
    var IdR = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(imagePart);
    string FileExtension = uri.OriginalString.Split('.').Last();
    var filename = uri.ToString().Split('/').Last();
    stream = doc.Package.GetPart(uri).GetStream();
    Bitmap b = new Bitmap(stream);
    string FilePath = @"C:\test"." + FileExtension;
    b.Save(FilePath);
}
```

Below will help you get the embedded object in word document like: Visio, MP3 video.

```
var IdR = doc.MainDocumentPart.GetIdOfPart(embeddedobjectpart);
string FileExtension = embeddedobjectpart.Uri.OriginalString.Split('.').Last();
FileExtension = "vsd";
stream = doc.Package.GetPart(embeddedobjectpart.Uri).GetStream();
long length = stream.Length;
byte[] byteStream = new byte[length];
stream.Read(byteStream, 0, (int)length);
string FilePath =@"C:\test"." + "." + FileExtension;
fstream = new FileStream(FilePath, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)
fstream.Write(byteStream, 0, (int)length);
fstream.Close();
```